# NullPointerException when inflating an item view of a RecyclerView through viewBinding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewbinding

I have a multi module application. In the module `ui` I have the item I want to show in the RecyclerView, in the module `checkout` there is the fragment that contains the RecyclerView.

CheckoutFragment

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.checkoutCartList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        binding.checkoutCartList.adapter = CheckoutAdapter(arrayOf(CartItem("xxx", 1, "9,99 €")))
    }
```

CheckoutAdapter

```
class CheckoutAdapter(private val list: Array<CartItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckoutAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemCheckoutCartProductBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.bind(list[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size

    class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemCheckoutCartProductBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: CartItem) {

        }
    }
}
```

When running the app, I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: it.xxxx.app.dev:id/add_item
at it.xxxx.ui.databinding.ItemCheckoutCartProductBinding.bind(ItemCheckoutCartProductBinding.java:155)
at it.xxxx.ui.databinding.ItemCheckoutCartProductBinding.inflate(ItemCheckoutCartProductBinding.java:87)
```

ItemCheckoutCartProductBinding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/view_32dp_space">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card_image_left"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/view_128dp_space"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/view_128dp_space"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/view_16dp_space"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:strokeColor="@color/colorGrey"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_16dp_space"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_red" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/product_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/view_24dp_space"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font_family_bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_16sp_size"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card_image_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/view_24dp_space"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_8dp_space"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/view_24dp_space"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card_image_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/product_description"
        app:strokeColor="@color/colorGrey"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_8dp_space"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/remove_item"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/view_12dp_space"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/view_12dp_space"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_minus"
                android:tint="@color/colorGrey" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/product_quantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/view_16dp_space"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_family_bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_14sp_size"
                tools:text="1" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_item"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/view_12dp_space"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/view_12dp_space"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
                android:tint="@color/colorGrey" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/delete_product_from_cart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/view_24dp_space"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_24dp_space"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font_family_regular"
        android:text="@string/common_delete"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_12sp_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card_image_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/quantity_selector" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/total_product_price_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font_family_bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_16sp_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/delete_product_from_cart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:text="4,20$" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If instead of using viewbinding I use the old way as wrote here https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview, works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: debugging a bit I have seen that using findViewById, the views corresponding to add_item, remove_item and quantity_selector are null, but all the others are correctly initialized. I don't know what can be

Answer (score 0):

The added code looks perfectly fine. Just invalidate and clear the cache.
Also please make sure you have used "binding.addItem" instead of add_item.

If possible please post complete Adapter code.

Also try ImageView instead of androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView just for checking purpose.

Comment: nope doesn't work